# Repast symphony @ScheduleMethod issue

Tags: repast-simphony

For some reason my method doesn’t get called when I use @ScheduledMethod. Have no idea what is wrong as I used it before and everything was fine.

Here is the code:

```
import repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduledMethod;

public class WindGen {

private double power;

@ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1, priority = 2)
private void generatePower() {

    int t = SystemOperator.getT();

    power = 20 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(t * 360 / 48) + 30);

}

public double getPower() {
    return power;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Dina.

Answer (score 2):

because your method is private. You need to change it to public to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simiar issue with @ScheduledMethod: it simply did not execute my method.

However, I did get it running by scheduling the method in a different way, 
which could look for you as follows:

```
ISchedule schedule = RunEnvironment.getInstance().getCurrentSchedule();
ScheduleParameters  generate = ScheduleParameters.createRepeating(start = 1, interval = 1, priority = 2);
schedule.schedule(generate , this ,"generatePower");
```

I suggest you try executing this code snippet once, at the very beginning and (perhaps) in the same class.

You will find further information on scheduling in the 
[Repast Simphony FAQ](http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/RepastSimphonyFAQ.pdf).

Hope it helps, Thorben